# How to get an action bar on an activity stared by imagebutton from a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I'm trying to add an action bar to an activity which is sarted from an ImageButton inside a fragment. I have added the code, but my app force closes on click of the image button.

abcd.java

```
package hind.jai.com.jaihind;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;


/**
 * Created by Rishik on 14-06-2015.
 */
public class abcd extends Activity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.abcd);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="hind.jai.com.jaihind" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <!-- <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> -->
        <activity
            android:name=".splash"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"

            ></activity>
        <activity

             android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
            android:name=".abcd" ></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

abcd.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

about.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/about"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:background="@drawable/image2"
        android:onClick="Onclick"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

about.java

```
package hind.jai.com.jaihind;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by sukhvir on 17/04/2015.
 */
public class about extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    ImageButton Img;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        return inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.about, container, false);


    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        //get the button view
        Img = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        //set a onclick listener for when the button gets clicked
        Img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //Start new list activity
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent Intent = new Intent(getActivity(), abcd.class);
                startActivity(Intent);

            }
        });


    }

}
```

this "about" is the fragment from where I have started an activity "abcd" via the imagebutton.

Comment: Opps sorry forgot to add it, updated main thread @Nilesh

Comment: give us some logcat, I don't understand completely,  the problem is the action bar or the activity that crashes?

Comment: and give us more code :)

Comment: where is ImageButton there in xml ?

Comment: the problem is, when I'm trying to add the action bar the activity crashes, updating with the logcat on the main thread, gimme some time. @AndreaCinesi

Comment: @Nilesh updated the thread once again, adding the logcat Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Try to use getSupportActionBar() instead ofgetActionBar() method.

Try this code

```
package hind.jai.com.jaihind;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity

/**
 * Created by Rishik on 14-06-2015.
 */
public class abcd extends Activity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.abcd);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: Getting these errors now,Error:(11, 27) error: cannot find symbol class Activity
Error:(13, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable super
Error:(14, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)
Error:(15, 31) error: cannot find symbol method getActionBar()

Comment: I mean what of the two answers , have add the minimum sdk ? or have you use getSupportActionBar? :)

Comment: this thing I have tried,Try to use getSupportActionBar() instead ofgetActionBar() method.
import "android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity"

Errors are these:
Error:(11, 27) error: cannot find symbol class Activity
Error:(13, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable super
Error:(14, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)
Error:(15, 31) error: cannot find symbol method getSupportActionBar()

Comment: and then instead of getActionBar use getSupportActionBar,  also i recommend to try uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11

Comment: I cant find android:minSdkVersion="11" line in my manifest, I'm a newbie, please help

Comment: you have to insert this <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> before <application

Comment: write 11 not 8, if you want i post a complete manifest example

Comment: Yes sure, 
I have tried editing, but I guess, I doing something wrong, 
<application
        uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     
Errors
Error:Attribute name "uses-sdk" associated with an element type "application" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
Error:Cannot read packageName from C:\Users\Rishik\AndroidStudioProjects\JaiHind\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: you have forget the /> after "11"

Comment: and don't delete  anything just copy between package and application

Comment: Android studio isn't allowing me to do that, It doesnt runs the app. Says wrong configuration

Comment: what is your min sdk ?

Comment: in Android studio it's not more important min sdk in Manifest cause it is in Gradle.file , so try my first answer mate

Comment: It is ICS , sorry I dont remember the number, this project was started by my friend

Answer (score 0):

You can access all of the Activities methods from a fragment by doing `getActivity()` anywhere inside a fragment.
So, to access Action bar, do

```
getActivity().getActionBar();
```

or, if you are using newer appcompat activities and toolbars,

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```

Your question was not clear, but hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: No, I'm not looking for something like that, and what I;m trying to do is, I want an activity to be started from an image button which is there inside a fragment, the new activity should have an action bar.

Comment: inside the fragment, do `startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),newActivity.class));`

Comment: I have already started the activity, the activity is working perfect( check my about.java file)but when I'm trying to add the actionbar, it forcecloses.

Answer (score 0):

If you could share your stacktrace, that would really help to determine what exactly is causing problem.

Nonetheless, I think you are getting **NullPointerException** exception because **getActionBar()** returns null in your case because in you set your activity theme as

> Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

which correspond to support library.

Try extending your activity from **AppCompatActivity** and then use getSupportActionBar() method to get actionbar.

Your should also change your actionbar from import **android.app.ActionBar** to **android.support.v7.app.ActionBar**.

Code:

```
package hind.jai.com.jaihind;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;

/**
  * Created by Rishik on 14-06-2015.
*/
public class abcd extends AppCompatActivity{
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.abcd);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: hey harry pery, I have tried using android.support.v7.app.ActionBar, with support method, as you mentioned, but I'm gettings errors, please check my comments with Andrea, thanks a lot

Comment: Seems like you are having a syntax error. What are you using AndroidStudio or Eclipse?

Comment: From what I gather you are using AndroidStudio. AndroidManifest in android studio does not have any attribute **uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"**, it have a separate build.gradle file from where you can change your minSdkVersion, that's why you are getting build errors. Try removing this attribute and then compile the project. Also your minSdkVersion is not causing any errors. The answer by andreas is misleading.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I'm using Android Studio, sorry for late responses, my internet is screwed up. 
an you please help me out mate?

Comment: tried, errors once again :( 
Error:(3, 30) error: cannot find symbol class AppCombatActivity
Error:(11, 27) error: cannot find symbol class AppCombatActivity
Error:(13, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable super
Error:(14, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)

Comment: It's not **AppCombatActivity**, it's **AppCompatActivity**  [see here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html)

Comment: Sorry my bad, still I'm facing errors mate,Error:(3, 19) error: cannot find symbol class AppCompatActivity
Error:(11, 27) error: cannot find symbol class AppCompatActivity
Error:(13, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable super
Error:(14, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)

Comment: go to Build option in menu bar in AndroidStudio and click on Rebuild Project. See if that helps.

Comment: No mate, its not working. again the same set of errors

Comment: try syncing your project with gradle files (gradle icon with downward pointing arrow in android studio) and if even this does not solve your problem then you are doing something wrong in your AndroidManifest or build.gradle file.

Comment: also did you remove minSdk attribute from your AndroidManifest file?